# Override edit/new/create behavior in Refinerycms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I need to change edit/create methods in Pages controller (or any custom generated engine), but can't find any. I has overrode all the controllers and tried searching the whole project for any "def edit" and did not find any.

I am new to Rails and I don't understand how this works. debug(params) points to refinery/admin/pages when I try to edit page, but there is no edit methods nor in admin or pages controller. So where the request is actually going when I hit update button or creating new page?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what's wrong.

When you do "override controller=*" it's don't actually overrides all the controllers, so the pages_controller.rb in controllers/refinery/ apparently is only the half of the pages controller. The real controller I needed is the one in controllers/refinery/admin which appears when you do "override controller=refinery/admin/*.

Still figuring out where is the create and edit actions, but at least I found new and update actions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Rails and Refinery world but maybe I can help.

Have you read this: [Extending Controllers and Models with Decorators](http://refinerycms.com/guides/extending-controllers-and-models-with-decorators)

In my case, I had to modify a parameter before saving it to Database, basically making sure it is UPPERCASE. So I did this:

```
Refinery::Routes::Admin::RoutesController.class_eval do
  before_filter :uppercase_region, :only => [:create, :update]

  protected

  def uppercase_region
    params[:route][:region].upcase!
  end
end
```

Maybe with a filter it is enough for you. I suppose here you can override also the create and update actions.

You'll see that in the generated engines you have something like this:

```
crudify :'refinery/routes/route',
        :title_attribute => 'name',
        :xhr_paging => true
```

If you follow that code you get to the "crud.rb" file: [crud.rb](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/blob/master/core/lib/refinery/crud.rb#L51)

Here you can read how the actions look like. So now you can create your own in the "decorator" file, as explained in the tutorial.

Hope this is useful to someone.